# Minimal glmnet example for factors

Tags: r, regression, glmnet

I am trying to understand how to use the R package glmnet.

Suppose I have a dataset, representing games played between two teams, with the 'win' column defining the result.

```
library(RcppAlgos)
library(dplyr)

data <- RcppAlgos::permuteGeneral(c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"), 2, repetition = TRUE) %>% 
as.data.frame() %>% setNames(c("team1", "team2")) %>% mutate(win = rbinom(25, 1, 0.5))
```

where 1 represents that team1 won, and 0 represents that team1 lost.

I now want to run this data through glmnet, with the 'won' column as the response.

I know that I need to use model.matrix with my factor variables, but it doesn't seem to me that that would give the right result.

For example:

```
x <- model.matrix(data$win ~ data$team1 + data$team2)
fit <- glmnet(x, data$win)
```

Can anyone help?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you think it won't give you the right result? What made you suspicious?

Comment: When I use plot(fit), I get a warning that it's meaningless. Also, I'm not able to generate predictions

Comment: What warning do you get? It works for me. How do you try to generate predictions? How does your code looks like?

Comment: I don't get any warnings or errors. However, your code is treating the outcome (zero or one) as a numeric variable. It looks like you actually want a logistic regression with the outcome being treated as categorical. To do that, the code would be : `fit2 <- glmnet(x, data$win, family="binomial")`. To get predictions on the probability scale for the input data, run `predict(fit2, newx=x, type="response")`. Predictions with your original model would be `predict(fit, newx=x)`.

Comment: The [`glmnet` Vignette](https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/glmnet/glmnet_alpha.html) has various examples showing how to generate models and process the results.

Comment: ...also try to build your matrix model like this `x <- model.matrix(win ~ team1 + team2, data = data)[,-1]`, otherwise you'll end up having 2 intercepts. You can see the coefficients like `coef(fit)` or `coef(fit, s=0.043130)` (i.e. at lambda value = 0.043130). Remember that `glmnet` returns a set of models based on different lambda values and not 1 single model.

Comment: Thank you very much for your responses guys. They have been a helpful starting point :)